# How to filter for authorized users in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I would like to put together a query where I can check whether a particular user makes changes to work items under a particular Area Path in Team Services. The query editor offers me as authorized person ( [ME] or @Me) but I don't know what value should be entered there in case of another person. The query editor does not offer other people name.

[image]

I already tried with the

- person's email address ( jack.jones@domain.com ) which is used for authentication
- person username alias ( jack.jones ) (you can find it under his/her profile ticket)
- person natural name ( Jack Jones )

Neither one is working.

Comment: Have you tried using the 'Changed By' field instead?

Comment: The problem is the same if I use that field. There is no pre-populated combobox just a freetype field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS supports setting alerts for yourself, if you have proper permission, you can also set alerts for a team or a team member.

You can only select [ME] or @Me in alerts. But there are several ways to achieve want you want:

1. Edit the "Send to" item and specify the email addresses:

[image]

2. Add the users to a team, then create an alert for a team.  For the team context, the alert query interprets the **@Me** variable as anyone who is a member of the team.
3. Create an alert for a team member. Choose the name of the team member from the drop down list, or type the name in the search box. Then, create an alert:

[image]

Useful link: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/alerts-and-notifications

Comment: The nasty and annoying in TFS is that, if you can see one query related feature somewhere you won't find somewhere else. In the plain query screen you can do that you described above. BUT, you cannot using the alerts setup.